# Webpart, in VS2015, has red X when adding Microsoft Office Developer tools

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio-2015, office-365-groups

I recently downloaded VS2015 Community Edition.  I opened the solution I was running in an enterprise edition previously.  The solution is a sharepoint application.  I installed Microsoft Office Developer Tools from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=51683)

When I open my webparts, I see red x next to some folders.

[image]

From googling, it appears to be connected with the config of the dev tools but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new SharePoint project to check if it works.

And try to copy the folders from the old SharePoint solution to the new one.